# Why Glassfish rejects all my authentication efforts under Netbeans 7.3.1?

Tags: java, jsf-2, netbeans, spring-security, glassfish-4

I'm using Glassfish 4.0, Netbeans 7.3.1.

I added new server to my project, it created default domain - domain1. 
Glassfish advertized that I can use "anonymous" login and empty password in order to login.
I met question on stackoverflow.com that default login is admin and password is adminadmin.

I created simple facelet, with form action - `POST` query (spring-security authentification action, `j_security_check`)
When I press submit button **Glassfish forces me to enter login and password**.

I tried all versions - admin/adminadmin, anonymous/{empty password}. Also I tried to change server parameters (username, password) in netbeans' servers Tab - by default they are empty. I filled them with admin/adminadmin and anonynous/{empty} - doesn't work.

Could anybody tell me why glassfish rejects all my login efforts **even if I try all default or advertized variants**? Also I noticed strange behavior that sometimes Glassfish can start only once. In order to start it second time I had to change domain.xml file in domain1 folder to pre-saved "clear" one.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `j_security_check` in your application will not accept credentials from your server users but from your application users.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncby/index.html how you can it.

Comment: I know that `j_security_check` accept credentials from users. This action sends POST query to some internal spring's servlet and it finally goes to Glassfish. In other words Glassfish tries to identify each incoming request and **my problem is disable this over-securng**.[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579385/spring-security-doesnt-work-on-glassfish-v3) an idea about modifying `default-web.xml` was posted and I'm going to try it and report here about results.

Comment: Yeah, modyfying `default-web` worked! Authetication dialog disapperad! Now I have other error but this other problem...